# How to generate Access Token for Google Cloud API?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, access-token, google-oauth

I tried the following way

```
public class GoogleOAuth2 {
String authURL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
String tokenURL = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";

public void execute() {
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(tokenURL);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id",
                "*********"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "*****"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "Authorization Code"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_url", "https://localhost:8080"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
        String body = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println(body);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Catched an error in Authenticating user : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}}
```

Now, this shows this error ,
(I have tried grant-type as Code,password,offline also)

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: Authorization Code"
}
```

What m i missing?
Can you please guide me to the right direction? I have Tried using Postman and i was able to get an access Token from here.

[image]